# Woocommerce Remove Fields from the View-Order page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce version 2.4.6 if that's helpful at all.  I'm trying to modify the view-order page of a specific order.  The web address would be something like:

http://www.edventurelearning.com/my-account/view-order/244/

The page lists the status of the order, the order details, customer details, and then the billing address.  I'd like to remove the billing address section since I don't collect the data and all the payments are done through paypal.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get rid of the Billing Address field from showing up on the page.  (I've already removed the field from the checkout process).  view-order.php is the file that creates the page and I can modify it but the code that creates all the order detail sections is lumped into:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', $order_id );
```

I've found the `woocommerce_view_order` function which is called by `woocommerce_order_details_table` which is called by `wc_get_template`.  At that point I get lost and I figure there has to be an easier way to modify what is displayed.  All I need to do is remove the Billing Address section.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I posted this in the woocommerce forums and one answer was:

An easier way is to hide it using custom css. I can't see your view order page as I'm not a customer and haven't bought anything, but on my site I would use:

```
.woocommerce-view-order .woocommerce header.title,
.woocommerce-view-order .woocommerce address
{display:none}
```

Not very subtle but at least there is no need to maintain a custom version of the relevant template.

That post can be seen here:

[Wordpress Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-fields-from-the-view-order-page?replies=2#post-7541155)

Comment: Don't use this if you need to hide this information for user privacy reasons as you can still see the information on HTML inspection.